# how to delete selected records of jqgrid in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

can anyone help in deleting selected records of jqgrid in asp.net c# for the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var x = screen.width;

        $(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery("#table1").jqGrid({
                url: 'griddata.aspx/DepartmentData?id=1',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',

                colNames: ['Department', 'Dept Code', 'Contact Person', 'Contact Phone','Contact Email'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 55 },
                        { name: 'Dept Code', index: 'Dept Code', width: 90 },
                        { name: 'Contact Person', index: 'Contact Person', width: 40, align: 'center' },
                        { name: 'Contact Phone', index: 'Contact Phone', width: 40, align: 'center' },
                        { name: 'Contact Email', index: 'Conatct Email', width: 40, align: 'center' }],


                pager: '#pager1',
                rowNum: 15,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                sortname: 'Department',
                sortorder: "desc",
                loadonce: true,
                loadtext: "Loading....",
                shrinkToFit: true,
                multiselect: true,
                emptyrecords: "No records to view",
                width: x - 40,
                height: 230,
                rownumbers: true,
                caption: 'DepartmentTable'


            });
            jQuery("#table1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { edit: true, add: true, del: true });


        });

 </script>
```

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?  The jqGrid documentation notoriously has trouble keeping up with its development, so it's tough to see exactly how you're handling the deletes, other than passing an option to the grid initializer.  Do you have a link to the exact documentation for this version of the delete functionality?  Additionally, where is your disconnect?  Do you have the server-side functionality in place and just need the eventing model on the client-side with an AJAX call to make it happen?  Or do you have the client-side code but need an AJAX listener on the server?  etc.?

Comment: i have a trash icon on pager of my jqgrid...when i select a row and click the trash icon(for delete) it says no url is set...i am a beginner....i havent added functionality for delete anywhere i just want the trash icon on jqgrid to delete the selected record... thanx

Comment: it would help me to add some event handler in my code behind(aspx.cs) page

Comment: @bhargav: Do you just need the record deleted on the client-side, or do you also need it deleted from your actual data store?  You probably don't want an event handler in the code-behind file for this page.  You don't want to be dealing with post-backs with jqGrid, it's designed for a more AJAX-based approach.  You'll want a separate server-side handler (a page with no UI, or better yet an HttpHandler without all the overhead of a page, or maybe an Action if you can use MVC... any way you do it you'll have to make sure you're sending correct headers, etc.) for the server-side deletes.

Comment: i need the record to be deleted on server side...i have even written a stored procedure to delete the reocrd from databse but i dont know how to call that in code behind when user clicks on trash icon

Comment: @bhargav: Calling the stored procedure (or interacting with the database in any way) from your server-side .NET code is an entirely separate concept than what you have here.  Best to keep the two separated mentally when working on them, otherwise you may confuse yourself regarding the architectural layout of the code you're writing.  The JavaScript code interacts with the .NET website and knows nothing of the database.  The database interacts with the .NET website and knows nothing of the JavaScript.

Comment: @David how can i delete a record from the jqrid usin onclick event...

Comment: @bhargav: What onclick event?  As I said, I'm not sure about the eventing model that jqGrid is using in this case.  I thought it was handling the client-side delete automatically and just looking for a URL to which it would send the delete request to the server?  (Ideally, it would be hitting the URL before doing the client-side delete, in case the server-side delete fails.)

Comment: my idea is to use a button and then in code behind onclick of tht button i need to delete the selected records of jqgrid...if possible i want to use that onclick to the trash icon(on pager of jqgrid) or just another button might work

Comment: @David this is the griddata page that brings data into jqgrid

Comment: @bhargav: I've updated my answer with some more information based on these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Might be time to start moving this conversation from comments to an answer...)

I'm not 100% familiar with this particular functionality in jqGrid (as I said in a comment, its own documentation has a hard time keeping up with its development), but essentially there should be one of two things that the "delete" functionality is looking for:

- A URL to send a pre-determined delete request.  Likely a GET request with some parameters on the query string, though that's not certain.  This URL may be highly configurable.  You'll need to find where/how to configure it (unless you can point me to the documentation/tutorial you're using and perhaps I can help from there).
- A client-side event handler for the deletes.  This would likely be something to which you'd attach an inline function in your JavaScript code.  This function, for your needs, will probably just be an AJAX call (via jQuery, naturally) to a server-side resource of your design/choosing which would handle the deletes.

From my past experience with jqGrid, and from your comments so far, it sounds like the first option is what it's looking for.  Somewhere in its initialization jqGrid needs you to set a URL to which it will send deletes.  This URL will be of your own design for your server-side code.

That means you also need to create a server-side handler to make this happen.  If you're using ASP .NET MVC, this is very easy.  A controller action will do the job just fine and can even return JSON very easily if anything needs to be sent back to the client-side.  If you're using WebForms, you have two primary options:

- Create a new page which has no UI (delete everything but the Page directive from the .aspx file).  It would check the incoming parameters, perform the action you need on the server-side (delete the record from the database, most likely), then manually craft a response.  You'll want to look into manipulating response headers for this, because it will probably expect the content type to be `application-json` or something of that nature.
- Create an `HttpHandler` which doesn't have the overhead of an .aspx page (and is a lot more like a controller action in that respect).  It would do the same thing, performing the server-side action and all that, and manually crafting a response.  (I'm assuming a particular response is expected, such as an indication of success or failure which may be in the form of an actual server error such as a 500.)

Your jqGrid initializer would set some property which configures the URL it uses to send delete requests to the server.  This would have to include the ID of the row being deleted, of course.  Essentially, you have a *lot* of manual control over what's going on.  It's not really plug-and-play, you have to write and understand the code.

**Edit:** If you're doing the client-side delete on the server-side then you don't need a lot of jqGrid involvement here.  You'd just have an ASP .NET button which posts back to the server, deletes the record, and re-binds the page data (to include the jqGrid data) to the new data set from the server.  Keep in mind that this post-back model is not really what jqGrid is meant to use.

You can add a button on the client-side for jqGrid deletes, as demonstrated [here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (click on "Live Data Manipulation" on the left and then on "Delete Row" to see the example).  Then you'd simply write a JavaScript function for that button's click event to handle the delete.  Their example does the client-side delete:

```
$("#dedata").click(function(){
  var gr = jQuery("#delgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
  if( gr != null )
    jQuery("#delgrid").jqGrid('delGridRow',gr,{reloadAfterSubmit:false});
  else
    alert("Please Select Row to delete!");
});
```

Of course, you'll need to add to that (as I said in a comment, *before* the client-side delete in case there's an error on the server) an AJAX call to handle the server-side delete as I'd talked about above.  The most straight-forward way would be to use the [jQuery .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.  This would call your server-side resource (controller action, HttpHandler, or .aspx page) that would handle the server-side delete and return success or failure.

Keep in mind the server-side delete from the database is an entirely separate topic than what you're doing here.  It's also very well covered in ADO .NET and LINQ and Entity Framework articles and tutorials all over the internet.  Essentially, all you're looking to do there (based on your comments so far) is call a SQL stored procedure from .NET code.  Google will yield many results on this.

Comment: thanx a lot david for ur time...i have searched a lot on using client side deletion...it was hard to understand...so i finally decided to go for server side deletion which involves postback....

Comment: @bhargav: For a beginner that's generally the way to go.  Don't get me wrong, I fully endorse the use of jqGrid and AJAX where appropriate for a better user experience.  But you seem to be biting off more than you can chew at the moment.  Hopefully you'll come back to this approach someday though, because it's definitely worth it :)

Comment: @David  i need a solution for my code using url for delete without any postbacks....i just need the best way of deleting the record from jqgrid and at the same time it should also get deleted from database..i think i hav been messin with u for too long but i need a solution..so im kinda desparate...i need a right approach as u hav mentioned above...:)  lol im forced to chew more than i can bite everyday..

Comment: @bhargav: In order to write/debug/maintain it you will need to understand some concepts that appear to be very new to you.  Just be aware of that.  If you can use a button (as opposed to the trash can icon) then go with the edit I had added to my question above.  Add a regular HTML button (as in the jqGrid sample) and attach to its click event as demonstrated.  Then use the jQuery .ajax method to call a handler on the server-side.  Just make sure you check for a successful response from the server before deleting the client-side record, to avoid end user confusion.

Comment: $("#dedata").click(function() {
             var gr = jQuery("#table1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
             if (gr != null)
                 jQuery("#table1").jqGrid('delGridRow', gr, { reloadAfterSubmit: false });
             else
                 alert("Please Select Row to delete!");
         });

Comment: i have added above in the <script></script> part of aspx page..i have also added an asp button with ID = "dedata" in <body>...is the $(#dedata") the ajax calling part??...now what do i hav to do...

Comment: @bhargav: Why an ASP button?  I'd recommend a regular HTML button for this.  But if it needs to be an ASP button for some reason (beware of unwanted postbacks), then you'll need to refer to its `ClientID` property in your JavaScript code.  Its server-side ID will be different.  As for the AJAX part, you would use the jQuery .ajax() method that I linked to in my answer above.  It would be called within the `if` block of the click handler, before the client-side delete is done.  (Naturally, if the AJAX request returns an error, don't do the client-side delete.  Display an error instead.)

Comment: $("#<%=dedata.ClientID%>").click(function()..i hv changed it..now what do i do?

Comment: @bhargav: I'll be honest, it _really_ sounds like you don't understand what you're doing.  We're all happy to help here at Stack Overflow, but we won't really do the work for you.  For this to work in any meaningful (and supportable-by-you) way, you need to understand the disconnect between JavaScript and server-side code (.NET), how AJAX works, how web requests/responses work, and apparently how to interact with a database in your .NET code.

Comment: @bhargav: Now what you do is add a call to the jQuery .ajax() method to call your server-side resource which handles the delete and returns an indication of success or failure.  Honestly, there's not much more I can tell you without doing your project for you.

Comment: @David im happy the way you  are helpin me..i think i hav to do some homework on ajax calls....thanx anyways for all the help u hav done and for ur time..